# cloudera - change all attributes into uppercase

Tags: sql, cloudera-cdh

I have a variable, whose attributes were sometimes inserted as lowercase, and then tableau reads this as two different cases, when they are actually not. So all attributes must be uppercase, and I have not found a solution as how to do that in Cloudera.

the example :

attended
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
true
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
true
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE

So potentially a set statement, but how is that done when creating a table:

```
CREATE TABLE new
STORED AS PARQUET AS
SELECT 
cust_no, 
statement, 
attended
from old
```

How can I change it within the create a table clause?
Many thanks

Comment: I used: <attended = upper(attended),>  - but funny enough "True", becomes then "true" and "true" becomes "false" - even though this is not a where clause =, hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_upper.asp

```
CREATE TABLE new
STORED AS PARQUET AS
SELECT 
upper(cust_no), 
upper(statement), 
upper(attended)
from old
```

add `upper` only to those columns which you want to make it uppercase